# Generate web view of data in oracle tables

Tags: oracleforms

I have a requirement based on the following that already exists in the system

1. persistence store is Oracle 11g. no containers in use.
2. db is on linux 5.6 server.
3. there are a bunch of related tables - about 10
4. there are a few views on these tables to ease access of related data

requirements -

1. display data in tables/views in a browser.
2. also allow editing some data via the page.
3. navigation from one page to another
4. performance is not a constraint as of now.

Where should I start from, what to use, how to use?
note - constraints - time (2 weeks) and money (no sanctions yet).

Comment: This is tagged Oracle Forms. So do you have to (want to) use Forms?

Comment: in order to display in a browser i got to have html files. So can i generate a quick html from reading records in DB? it got to be generic enough since all tables will not have same set of columns.

Comment: we finally built a webapp to view tables in browser. it was built using php. we gather the format from the data dictionary. the app is built using php. we havent given access to edit the data though!

Comment: we have two solutions to the problem. 
1. using datatables (datatables.net) with php or python.
2. webapp built for viewing and editing data with django/python

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are interested in [Oracle Apex](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html)?